# Determine the start-up activity at runtime

Tags: android, android-intent

I have an application which shows a login screen as the first activity.

Due to some new language features in my application, I now want to optionally show a 'select language screen' which allows the user to select a language before displaying the login screen.

Depending on an application setting, which indicates the valid languages, I want to either show the login screen, or the language screen assuming there is more than one language to select from.

As far as I can see, I've got 3 options.

1. I could create a splash screen activity, which is a blank screen. This activity could determine whether to show the language screen, or the login screen, and just start the activity.
2. I've already sub-classed the Application object, so I'm guessing that I could fire off the relevant activity directly from the `OnCreate` method of the application?
3. Always show the language selection screen as the first activity, and if it's not needed, just fire up the login activity.

I was wondering if there's a preferred way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Why can't you just show a non-cancelable dialog on your login screen? You can assume English to be the default language and if the user changes it then you can restart the activity if needed or change the strings yourself.

The second approach won't work because you need to have an activity that starts with the app; you can't just start an `android.app.Application` instance.

Comment: I was looking for a tidy way of doing this, and hoping that my option 2 would have been possible. I've ended up using option 3, as that allows me to control the flow properly.

Comment: IMO this option is tidier and less resourceful, esp. if you use a `DialogFragment`. You likely only show the language selection screen the first time the app starts, so it's not as efficient to open a "ghost" activity every time.

That being said, it will still work and probably will not be noticeable by the user.

Comment: Also you can have the default language be based on the Android system language (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html)

Comment: This application is used as a kiosk application, and will be used by multiple clients per machine, all speaking a variety of languages. The 'language' selection will be displayed (if relevant) for each client using the system. I think that option 3. is less resourceful, as the password screen will more than likely have to be re-loaded each time someone chooses a language. I've implemented it using option 3, and it works fine, unless you see any problems with using that method?

Answer (score 0):

What about showing the login screen as the first screen, and add Preferences activity that users can access to select a different language.

Comment: This won't work because the login screen won't be showing the translated text asking for the username/password (or preferences). The language selection has to be the first screen, and only consist of the language name.

Comment: can you explain more to me

Comment: Well, the whole point in the user selecting their language, is so that it can display screens with translated text, if you show the PIN screen straight away, this will contain text in a possibly foreign language.

Comment: Ok, I think English is the most common language so it can be the default language and the settings icon can be placed in the actionbar or as an icon somewhere.

Comment: No, English isn't the most common language for our application, it is used in China, London and Singapore. It HAS to work with the language screen up front, otherwise we lose 1/2 of our client base.

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak to options 1 or 2, but I have used an approach similar to option 3.  In the onCreate for your language selection activity, if you determine it's not needed, just start an intent for the login activity.  This will run before the view is rendered, so the user will never see it.